# is reading a resource file from within JAR in a webapp same as reading from target/classes?

Tags: java, jar, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am rather new to web applications, I have a Jersey Application. I would need to deploy the jar on a server. 
I am reading my resource file successfully using the following approach (suggested in most answers to read a resource from JAR)

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("public/" + uriInfo.getPath());
```

When I try to look at the path the file is being loaded from it is something like

```
> C:\Users\....\..\myservice\target\classes\public\meta-data\myfile.txt
```

Is it correct to say that the resource is loaded from the jar? Because I would need to load it from the jar and not the local file system since it is a web app.

If not, what do I need to be doing so that I can read my resource file in a Web Application.

Comment: It most likely doesn't show the file being loaded from a jar file, because you are not running your code from a jar file when you test it.

Comment: I deployed the application on a remote server myself and I was able to access the resource there. So I guess the approach was right.